# conditional groupBy using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, laravel-4

I have a scenario where I need to `group by` my results from the database based on conditions from the UI. The example on the Laravel docs shows that I can perform `groupBy` like this:

```
$query->groupBy('col1','col2','col3');
```

But how do I do this if I want this to be conditional? Will the following work?

```
$query->groupBy(function($query){
    if($allowCol1 == true)
        $query->groupBy('col1');
    if($allowCol2 == true)
        $query->groupBy('col2');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this way you can

```
$query = Model::with('eagerload');
if($allowCol1 == true) $query->groupBy('col1');
if($allowCol2 == true) $query->groupBy('col2');
$variable = $query->get();
```